# Can't figure how to successfully skip line between my inputs in the form tag

Tags: html, css

Theredarmy.ca

Title says it all.

I tried using css display block

I tried br

I tried p

I suspected my stylesheet was overriding, but apparently inline css is prevalent.

No more ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use Flexbox:

```
#signup-form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

That will put the elements in rows. You'll need to fix your other CSS attributes to make them play nice with the flex layout.

Comment: Oddly switches layout but at least I get something different!!

Comment: Yes, you'll need to adjust the left margins and sizing of the input elements. Maybe add some padding between them.

Comment: Thanks a bunch man, Stack overflow flooded me with thumbs down and 0 answers. I'll manage with this. Quick last question, do you think that configuring the padding/margins will fix my overlapping footer?